# Azure Bot OAuth 2 Generic Provider login failed status 500

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-bot-service, ory-hydra

we are developing a teams bot that requires authentication/authorization.
To authenticate/authorize the user, we use the OAUTH_PROMPT activity card.
Our OAuth Provider is Ory hydra and it is configured with the following settings for the Azure Bot:

OAuth 2 Generic Provider:

[image]

The login fails with a status of 500 and the message "Login failed" using the bot framework emulator and also within "Test connection".

Unfortunately, we don't know how to debug it and we haven't seen any other failure information.

So any tips on how to debug it or why it fails would be appreciated!

Comment: Asking few clarifying questions:

Comment: 1) Does the OAuth "Test Connection" work in Azure Bot? Ex: https://i.gyazo.com/b13df5b488f73cca790235ab1a09509d.png

Comment: 2) What region is the Azure Bot set to? 
Ex: https://i.gyazo.com/8a72de70c43116dbcaed8bf108f4bbb4.png

Comment: Hi @RamFattah, unfortunately the "Test connection" does not work either (as also mentioned in my initial post). The bot is in the Germany West Central region.

Comment: Thanks, what programming language is the bot written in?

Comment: @RamFattah Typescript.

Comment: hmm... i dont think the issue is related to the bot framework sdk. The authentication should initially work when testing in Azure Bot OAuth Connection before using the OAuth in the SDK. Were you able to figure out the issue? Are you able to provide the steps to reproduce this issue?